# Regex: Extract a string pattern from a string

Tags: php, regex

Want to extract a pattern **"Link":URL** from a string.
Example:

```
$str = 'I like dogs and cats. View here "Link":http://www.example.com and here "Link":http://www.example2.com';
if (preg_match_all('/"Link":(.*?)/', $str, $match) >= 1) {
    print_r($match);
}
```

Need to extract **"Link":http://www.example.com** and **"Link":http://www.example2.com**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use greedy dot, `'/"Link":(.*)/'`

Comment: Both `.*?` and `.*` only make sense if there's something to anchor it on both ends. Else matching for non-space characters would be adviseable.

Comment: @mario, i agree with you, for example `'/"Link":(.*?)$/'` or `'/"Link":(.*)$/'`

Comment: My question is clearly not a duplicate to the one suggested. My question is an attempt to apply the knowledge that would however have been gained from the suggested question. Regardless, thanks for the answer.

Comment: The answer just extracts all the string after that first match not just the match or matches in the string

Comment: This worked  `'/"Link":([a-z:\/\/\.]+)/'`